# android azure push notification to another user

Tags: android, azure, notifications, push

I insert message to database azure. 
In the message of has from_id and to_id.
How to send a push to which this to_id?

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

request.execute({success:sendPush});

push.gcm.send(null, item.message, {
            success:function(response) {
        console.log('Push notification sent: ', response);
    },error:
    function(error) {
        console.log('Error sending push notification: ', error);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the push.gcm.send method takes one or more "tag".  Tags uniquely identify one device or a group of devices, in your case, the _id of the device.  Currently it is null so the message will be sent to all devices registered.

Note that in your Android code onRegistered event, each device need to provide it's unique ID when registering to GCM like this:

```
ToDoActivity.mClient.getPush().register(gcmRegistrationID, new String[]{ "theDeviceID" } );
```